Are latitudes and longitudes the same in WGS84 and NAD83 system?
I am processing some drone data. I was provided ground control point's location information. The CSV file provides the latitudes, longitudes, and altitudes of those points. The projection system is defined NAD83(2011). The drone data processing software shows the default coordinate system of the software is WGS84.
If latitudes and longitudes are the same in those two system, can I just import the location information into the drone software, or do I have to make a shapefile using in NAD83 projection system and then reproject it to WGS84 in ArcGIS?

Have a look at the old questions and answers https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=wgs84+nad83.
